# Angular vary header and footer based on current module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

Currently my app is fairly simple with only a single module, however I'm looking to expand it with an admin dashboard. From a high-level view, I'm planning on splitting into 2 modules: one for the client-facing site, and an authed lazy admin module like this:
[Client and admin module diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVxkE.png)

I'm hung up as to how I should setup the header and footer components for these two sections of the site. With a single-module, single-"section" website, it's fairly easy to have a uniform header and footer across the app by placing them in the `app-component.html` like so:

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

My issue is that I want a *different* header and footer component when I'm in the admin section than when I'm on the "main" site.

I've been considering these ideas so far:

1. Get an `isLoggedIn` boolean from an `auth-service` to vary the header and footer content based on site section.

   - This is fairly straight-forward, but feels like a hack and exposes code that I would prefer to be behind an auth guard.
2. In each of the "view" components of the app, manually place in the `app-header` and `app-footer` components.

   - Again, this feels like a hack and would be tedious, but my app only really will have 5-10 separate view pages, so it could be manageable.
3. Use 3 routing modules: a `main-router`, `client-router`, and `admin-router`. The main router would direct between a `app-client-component` and `app-admin-component`, with the template contents of each being essentially the above `app-component.html`, but the routers would be the client and admin routers respectively.

   - This feels like the best long-term solution, but I feel like there should be a simpler solution to this.

If anyone has experienced this issue before or has any insight into how I should structure this, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create different layouts and reuse them. Your components will know nothing about header and footer - layout selection is in router config.
See this link:
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-routing-reusing-common-layout-for-pages-from-different-modules-440a23f86b57